# svcutil change Type of so all are same

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I want to omit assembly reference here and specify typeof to namespace which I provide with /n:

How do I do this?

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute
[assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute

[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof
```

Answer (score 0):

It was generating because of multiple namespaces in wsdl so I changed all those namespaces which resolved my issue